# Is there any performance impact when using AsNoTracking() on anonymous result?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I Know how entity framework AsNoTracking() method works but i want to know should we use this method also when selecting specific fields of entity?

for example is there any performance benefits between these two queries:
(getting result as an anonymous object)

```
DataContext.Customers.AsNoTracking().Select(x => new { x.FirstName, x.City.Name }).ToList();


DataContext.Customers.Select(x => new { x.FirstName, x.City.Name }).ToList();
```

Comment: The answer to this question is buried in a comment in the linked answer, "Anonymous classes don't represent the entity itself so they don't have tracking."  So AsNoTracking() doesn't matter in this case.